# How to merge duplicate accounts?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I had an account on StackOverflow and another here on SuperUser.

Yesterday, I saw an option on StackOverflow to merge accounts, and I tried to do so. Unfortunately, I probably did something wrong, and the result was a duplicate account here on SuperUser.  There are now two virtually identical users named "Mark T".

**How can I merge these two accounts (or get rid of the one not tied to StackOverflow)?**

Answer (score 6):

Go to https://superuser.com/contact and select *I need to merge user profiles*.

Enter the links to both profiles and the team will take care of it.

Answer (score 3):

> If you have two accounts that you would like to join together, please edit the ‘about me’ section of each profile to say “merge keep” and "merge delete" and then contact us. You will need to provide links to the two profiles you would like to merge - we'll merge the one you annotated "merge delete" into the one you annotated "merge keep".

https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts