# Merge superuser and stackoverflow accounts

Tags: support

I've just created an account here, but I see my reputation is 1 even though on stackoverflow it's about 175. In my user panel there are both accounts listed.

So my question is: Can I merge these accounts so that I collect reputation from both sites to one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge duplicate accounts?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1418/how-to-merge-duplicate-accounts)

Comment: No, it’s not the same. That other question is asking ‘‘Can I have a French passport and a German passport simultaneously?’’  ***This*** question is asking ‘‘Can I have a passport issued by the European Union?’’

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Super User account and other Stack Exchange accounts are separate, the rep doesn't get transferred<sup>*</sup> from Stack Overflow to other sites and vice versa. You'll have to earn the rep in Super User.

<sup>*</sup>*Except for association bonus: If you have rep > 200 on any Stack Exchange site, then you get a one-time 100 rep bonus when you associate account.*