# How to combine logins?

Tags: support, login

How do I combine a gmail log in account I have, and a facebook log in account?

I can not find the information anywhere.

I see [how to merge duplicate accounts](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1418/how-to-merge-duplicate-accounts) says to 'flag' but what is that exactly?

Sorry if I missed the answer somewhere, I have looked at lots of similar posts but not really understood what they mean.

Comment: What are the names of the accounts you have, can you link to them? On your user profile check *my logins* too.

Answer (score 1):

You can log in with any of the following accounts, and as long as the associated email address is the same, you will be logged in to your account:

- Google/Gmail
- Facebook
- Yahoo
- Stack Exchange

For those login providers, we only record your email address, and as long as the provider returns the same address, in you go. Once you're logged in, you can change or add logins by going to [your user profile](https://superuser.com/users/163802/user163802) and clicking on "my logins", then "add more logins".